# How to read in C# the Newline character in a SQLite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, newline

An app I'm currently working on needs to retrieve the `Newline (\n)` character in a `TEXT` Field stored in a `SQLite` DB. What is the corresponding character for `\n` in SQLite?
Because

```
string[] words = str.Split(new string[] { @"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `\r\n` - this is a general solution for Windows. For MAC is `\r`, for Unix is `\n`. Try all of them, and remove `@`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] words = str.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

No `@` before the `""`, otherwise it means `\` and `r` and `\` and `n`... or try

```
string[] words = str.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

depending on what the program saved in the db.

Now, if you really want to be sure to catch anything, you could...

```
string[] words = str.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n", StringSplitOptions.None);
```

The `@` [means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> A verbatim string literal consists of an **@ character followed by a
>   double-quote character**, zero or more characters, and a closing
>   double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim
>   string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted
>   verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In
>   particular, **simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode
>   escape sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals**. A
>   verbatim string literal may span multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Environment.NewLine.

```
// Summary:
//     Gets the newline string defined for this environment.
//
// Returns:
//     A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing
//     "\n" for Unix platforms.
   public static string NewLine { get; }


string[] words = str.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine} , StringSplitOptions.None);
```